# Gap beneath "Sticky Footer" - Only happens when I add tables?

Tags: html, css, html-table, footer

I'm battling with what seems to be a conflict between my table and footer. My end goal is to have a short "Sticky Footer" on a product page. Products are contained within a table.

As I stand right now- I've barely managed to get my footer to stick to the bottom of the view-port. I need it to be a lot shorter though- and when I change it's "height" dimension- rather than decreasing in height from the top down, it shrinks from the bottom up, creating an unsightly gap.

Here is my source code & style-sheet:

```css
@charset "utf-8";
/* CSS Document */
html,
html* {box-sizing: border-box; 
 margin: 0; 
padding: 0;
height: 100%}
body {
font-size: 1vw;
background: rgba(0,0,0,1.00);
 text-decoration: none;
 padding: 0em;
 margin: 0em;
 float: inherit;
 height: 100%
}
header {
 position: fixed;
 padding:0em;
 z-index: 1000;
 top: 0;
 left: 0;
 width: 100%;
 text-decoration: none;
 color: transparent}
nav {
 z-index: 400;
 top: 0;
 left: 0;
 opacity; .100;
 float: right;
 display: inline-block;
 width: 100%; height: 10%;
 text-decoration: none;
 font-size: 160%;
 font-family: Centaur;
 position: fixed;
 color: transparent}

menu {
 height: 5%;
 display: inline-block;
 float: right;
 text-decoration: none; color: transparent;}


a href{color: black;}
@font-face {
    font-family:Centaur;
    src: url('your_font.ttf');}
p{color: black; text-decoration: none; font-size: 12px}


<style type="text/css">
  ul {list-style: none;padding: 0%;margin: 0%;}
  ul li {display: block;position: relative;float: left;border: 0%}
  li ul {display: none;}
  ul li a {display: block;padding: 5px 10px 5px 10px;text-decoration: none;
           white-space: nowrap;color: #fff;}
  ul li a:hover {background-color:rgba(163,0,15,0.83);}
  li:hover ul {display: block; position: absolute;}
  li:hover li {float: none;}
li:hover {cursor: pointer;
  -webkit-transition: background-color 300ms ease-out;
  -moz-transition: background-color 300ms ease-out;
  -o-transition: background-color 300ms ease-out;
  transition: background-color 300ms ease-out;} 

li a:hover {background-color: rgba(118,118,118,1.00);
  cursor: pointer;
  -webkit-transition: background-color 300ms ease-out;
  -moz-transition: background-color 300ms ease-out;
  -o-transition: background-color 300ms ease-out;
  transition: background-color 300ms ease-out;}
  #drop-nav li ul li {border-top: 0%;}

/* 2nd Level Drop */
#drop-nav li:hover ul ul {
left:-9999px; padding: 0; margin: 0; top: 0; display: block; position: absolute;
}
#drop-nav ul li:hover ul { display: block;
left:100%; padding: 0; margin: 0
top:0;
}

nav{float: right; padding: left: 70%}



swords{height: 25%}
jumper{height: 50%}
p1{font-size: 68%}

/*TESTERCODE*/

#container {min-height: 100%}
#footer {background-color: black; position: relative; height: 55px;}

margin-top; -55px; clear: both;}
#wrapper {min-height: 100%; position: relative}
/*TESTERCODE*/

* {
 margin: 0;
}
html, body {
 height: 100%;
}
.page-wrap {
  min-height: 100%;
  /* equal to footer height */
 margin-bottom: -142px; 
}
.page-wrap:after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
}
.site-footer, .page-wrap:after {
  /* .push must be the same height as footer */
 height: 100px; 
}
.site-footer {
  background: black; text-align: center; color: lightgray; position: fixed;
}
```

```html
 <!doctype html>
<html>
<head> 

<script type="text/javascript">
function MM_swapImgRestore() { //v3.0
  var i,x,a=document.MM_sr; for(i=0;a&&i<a.length&&(x=a[i])&&x.oSrc;i++) x.src=x.oSrc;
}
function MM_preloadImages() { //v3.0
  var d=document; if(d.images){ if(!d.MM_p) d.MM_p=new Array();
    var i,j=d.MM_p.length,a=MM_preloadImages.arguments; for(i=0; i<a.length; i++)
    if (a[i].indexOf("#")!=0){ d.MM_p[j]=new Image; d.MM_p[j++].src=a[i];}}
}

function MM_findObj(n, d) { //v4.01
  var p,i,x;  if(!d) d=document; if((p=n.indexOf("?"))>0&&parent.frames.length) {
    d=parent.frames[n.substring(p+1)].document; n=n.substring(0,p);}
  if(!(x=d[n])&&d.all) x=d.all[n]; for (i=0;!x&&i<d.forms.length;i++) x=d.forms[i][n];
  for(i=0;!x&&d.layers&&i<d.layers.length;i++) x=MM_findObj(n,d.layers[i].document);
  if(!x && d.getElementById) x=d.getElementById(n); return x;
}

function MM_swapImage() { //v3.0
  var i,j=0,x,a=MM_swapImage.arguments; document.MM_sr=new Array; for(i=0;i<(a.length-2);i+=3)
   if ((x=MM_findObj(a[i]))!=null){document.MM_sr[j++]=x; if(!x.oSrc) x.oSrc=x.src; x.src=a[i+2];}
}
</script>
   
   

   
   <!--scroll script-->
   
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("a").on('click', function(event) {
    if (this.hash !== "") {
      event.preventDefault();
      var hash = this.hash;
      $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $(hash).offset().top
      }, 800, function(){
        window.location.hash = hash;
      });
    } // End if
  });
});
</script>

<!--end scroll script-->




<style type="text/css">
@import url("Centaur/stylesheet.css");
body,td,th {
 font-family: Centaur;
 font-size: larger;
}
body {
 background-color: black;
}
 
 /*hover*/

 #productimg:hover {
    opacity: 0.5;
    filter: alpha(opacity=50); /* For IE8 and earlier */
 }
 
 td{height: 20%}
 
<style>
 
 div#load_screen{
 background: rgba(215,215,215,1.00);
 opacity: 1;
 position: fixed;
    z-index:7000;
 top: 0px;
 width: 100%;
 height: 1600px;
}
div#load_screen > div#loading{
 color:rgba(215,215,215,1.00);
 width:120px;
 height:24px;
 margin: 300px auto;
}

.dropdown {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
}

.dropdown-content {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    background-color:#4D4D4D;
    min-width: 160px;
    box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
    display: block;
}

.desc {
    padding: 15px;
    text-align: center;
}
 
 table {
    font-family: arial, sans-serif;
    width: 20%;
}

td, th {
    text-align: left;
    padding: 8px; height: 20%
}

tr:{
    background-color: #dddddd;
}
</style>
<script>
window.addEventListener("load", function(){
 var load_screen = document.getElementById("load_screen");
 document.body.removeChild(load_screen);
});
</script>


 <meta charset="utf-8"></meta>
<title>Albion-Swords/Swords</title>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
<!--Style_Sheet-->
<link href="Albion Front Page Style Sheet.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>

<body style="position: relative; width: 100%; height: 100%; background-image: url(images/m_whitedrop-Recovered.jpg);
  background-position: center center;
   background-repeat:  no-repeat;
   background-attachment: fixed;
   background-size:  cover;">
<div id="load_screen"><div id="loading"><h1 style="color: black">LOADING...</h1></div></div>

<div class="page-wrap">
<div style="width: 100%; padding-bottom: " id="main">


<div class="logodiv"></div><div id="imgjumpy" style="vertical-align: bottom"></div><!--Header!-->

<header style="border-top: medium; border-color: black">
  
  <!--Navigation_Menu-->
  <nav style="padding-left: 70%">
   
   <ul id="drop-nav">
     <li><a href="Albion Front Page.html" style="color: black;">Home</a></li>
     <li><a id="products" href="Albion-Swords Sword Lines.html" style="color: black">Swords</a>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="Albion-Museum Line.html" style="color: black">Museum Line</a></li>
<li><a href="Albion-Swords Next Generation Line Swords.html" style="color: black">Next Generation</a></li>
 <li><a href="Albion-Swords Squire Line Swords.html" style="color: black">Squire Line</a></li>
  <li><a href="Albion-Swords Maestro Line Swords.html" style="color: black">Maestro Line</a></li>
          <li><a href="#" style="color: black">Skirmish Line</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" style="color: black">Special Edition</a></li>
      
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#" style="color: black">About</a>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#" style="color: black">Media</a></li>
      <li><a href="#" style="color: black">Story</a></li>
      <li><a href="#" style="color: black">Gallary</a></li>
      <li><a href="https://www.facebook.com/Albion-Swords-Limited-LLC-109838441137/" style="color: black">Facebook</a></li>
      <li><a href="https://twitter.com/albionswords?lang=en" style="color: black">Twitter</a></li>
      <li><a href="#" style="color: black">Testimonials</a></li>
</ul>
  </li>
  <li><a href="Albion News.html" style="color: black">News</a>
   <li><a href="Albion Order.html" style="color: black">Order</a>

   
  </nav>
<img src="images/Albion Web Logo.png" class="logo" style="z-index: 2000; width: 25%; padding-left: 3%; padding-top: 0% position: absolute"/></header>



<div name=tablecontainer style="padding-left: 30%">
<table style="float: left; width: 45%; height: 100%; position: absolute">
   
       
       <td><br><h3 style="text-align: center"><img src="images/NEXTGENMARK.png" width="5%" height="auto" alt=""/>The Albion Mark Next Generation Line<img src="images/NEXTGENMARK.png" width="5%" height="auto" alt=""/></h3>
 </h3></td><td></td>
    
       
        <tr>
   <td><h4 style="text-align: left"></h3><b>Iron Age & Roman Swords</b></h3></td>
    </tr>
       <tr>
        <td><img style="float: right" style="" src="images/CHERUSKER.png" width="90%" height="auto" alt=""/></td>
     <td style="width:20%"><p1 style="text-decoration: underline"><b>The Cherusker</b></p1><br><p1>Germanic War-Knife<br><b>$880.00</b></p1></td>
    </tr>
     <tr>
        <td><img style="float: right" src="images/AQUILIFER2.png" width="83.5%" height="auto" alt=""/></td>
   <td><p1 style="text-decoration: underline"><b>The Aquilifer</b></p1><br><p1>Fulham Gladius<br><b>$770.00</b></p1></td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><img style="float: right;" src="images/TIBERIUS2.png" width="83.5%" height="auto" alt=""/></td>
  <td><p1 style="text-decoration: underline"><b>The Tiberius</b></p1><br><p1>Fulham Gladius II<br><b>$770.00</b></p1></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><img style="float: right;" src="images/ALLECTUS2.png" width="83.5%" height="auto" alt=""/></td>
  <td><p1 style="text-decoration: underline"><b>The Allectus</b></p1><br><p1>Mainz Gladius<br><b>$770.00</b></p1></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><img style="float: right;" src="images/AUGUSTUS2.png" width="83.5%" height="auto" alt=""/></td>
  <td><p1 style="text-decoration: underline"><b>The Augustus</b></p1><br><p1>Mainz Gladius II<br><b>$770.00</b></p1></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><img style="float: right;" src="images/PEDITE2.png" width="83.5%" height="auto" alt=""/></td>
  <td><p1 style="text-decoration: underline"><b>The Pedite</b></p1><br><p1>Pompeii Gladius<br><b>$770.00</b></p1></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><img style="float: right;" src="images/TRAJAN2.png" width="83.5%" height="auto" alt=""/></td>
  <td><p1 style="text-decoration: underline"><b>The Trajan</b></p1><br><p1>Guttmann <br> Pompeii Gladius<br><b>$825.00</b> </p1></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><img style="float: right;" src="images/DECURIO2.png" width="100%" height="auto" alt=""/></td>
  <td><p1 style="text-decoration: underline"><b>The Decurio</b></p1><br><p1>(Roman Spatha)<br><b>$880.00</b></p1></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><img style="float: right;" src="images/AUXILIA.png" width="100%" height="auto" alt=""/></td>
  <td><p1 style="text-decoration: underline"><b>The Auxilia</b></p1><br><p1>(Roman Spatha)<br><b>$880.00</b></p1></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><img style="float: right;" src="images/ALARISSKETCH2.png" width="100%" height="auto" alt=""/></td>
  <td><p1 style="text-decoration: underline"><b>The Alaris</b></p1><br><p1>Spatha I <br> available for <br> 
advance reservation<br><b>$880.00</b></p1></td>
    </tr>
    
</table>
<!--END TABLE CONTAINER-->
</div>
<!--END TABLE CONTAINER-->
</table>

</div>
 </div>
 <footer class="site-footer"><br><br><div style="padding-left: 25%; padding-right: 25%; text-align: justify"><p1>Information sent to Albion Swords Ltd is kept strictly confidential. It is not shared or sold to other firms. Data may be used to send e-mail announcements which may be opted out of via email. Copyright (c) 2005: Albion Swords Ltd, LLC. This site and all pages and images contained therein unless otherwise indicated are property of Albion Armorers Swords Ltd, LLC and may not be reproduced or used without express consent. Site created and maintained by Howard & Amy Waddell & Cody Carter. Principal photography by: Leif Hansen, Søren Niedziella & Emma Martinson.</p1></div>
</footer>
</body>
</html>
```

My apologies for the mixed up code. I am using in-markup CSS as well as a style-sheet...

If the snippet does weird things, here is a screenshot:

[image: screenshot]

Comment: https://css-tricks.com/couple-takes-sticky-footer/ I believe that this is the one which I have used in the past - not too hard to implement, worked like a charm.

Comment: Not sure why, but it isn't working for me. I'm still having the same issue- except my footer gets pushed up to the middle of the page...

What could be pushing on my footer from below?

Comment: Okay, so I started a new page and attempted this without tables and it worked; however, the footer still displays across the middle of the page the moment I add my tables.

The footer shows up at the bottom of the view-port when the page firsts loads, but when I scroll, the view-port rolls past it- like it's staying where it originally appeared rather than following the view-port.